# Has anyone updated SwiftUI Popovers to work in Xcode beta-3?

Tags: popover, swiftui

Updated to Xcode beta-3, Popover was deprecated... having one hell of a time trying to figure out how to make it work again!?!?

1. It no longer "pops up" it slides up from the bottom.
2. It's no longer positioned or sized correctly, takes up the whole screen.
3. Once dismissed, it never wants to appear again.

This was the old code, that worked perfectly...

```
struct ExerciseFilterBar : View {
    @Binding var filter: Exercise.Filter

    @State private var showPositions = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: { self.showPositions = true } ) {
                Text("Position")
            }
            .presentation(showPositions ? Popover(content: MultiPicker(items: Exercise.Position.allCases, selected:$filter.positions),
                                                  dismissHandler: { self.showPositions = false })
                                        : nil)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

And this is the new code...

```
struct ExerciseFilterBar : View {
    @Binding var filter: Exercise.Filter

    @State private var showPositions = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: { self.showPositions = true } ) {
                Text("Position")
            }
            .popover(isPresented: $showPositions) {
                MultiPicker(items: Exercise.Position.allCases, selected:self.$filter.positions)
                .onDisappear { self.showPositions = false }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I ended up using PresentationLink just so I can move forward with everything else...

```
struct ExerciseFilterBar : View {
    @Binding var filter: Exercise.Filter

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            PresentationLink(destination: MultiPicker(items: Exercise.Position.allCases, selected:$filter.positions)) {
                Text("Position")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

It works, as far as testing is concerned, but it's not a popover.

Thanks for any suggestions!

BTW, this code is being in the iPad simulator.

Comment: It must be a bug. I am having the same problem. There is no way that is intended behavior. How frustrating! For a beta3 I think it is pretty worrying. At least they could have mention it in the release notes. There's no way they don't know popovers are broken.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX the code below works fine

```
struct ContentView : View {

@State var poSelAbove = false
@State var poSelBelow = false
@State var pick : Int = 1

var body: some View {

    let picker = Picker(selection: $pick, label: Text("Pick option"), content:
    {
        Text("Option 0").tag(0)
        Text("Option 1").tag(1)
        Text("Option 2").tag(2)
    })

    let popoverWithButtons =
        VStack {
            Button("Not Dismiss") {
            }
            Divider()
            Button("Dismiss") {
                self.poSelAbove = false
            }
        }
        .padding()

    return VStack {
        Group {
            Button("Show button popover above") {
                self.poSelAbove = true
            }.popover(isPresented: $poSelAbove, arrowEdge: .bottom) {
                popoverWithButtons
            }

            Divider()
            Button("Show picker popover below") {
                self.poSelBelow = true
            }.popover(isPresented: $poSelBelow, arrowEdge: .top) {
                Group {
                    picker
                }
            }
        }
        Divider()
        picker
            .frame(width: 300, alignment: .center)
        Text("Picked option: \(self.pick)")
            .font(.subheadline)
    }
    // comment the line below for iOS
    .frame(width: 800, height: 600)
}
```

On iOS (iPad) the popover will appear in a strange transparent full screen mode. I don't think this is intended. I have added the problem to my existing bug report.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yeah, I should've clarified I am having this issue on the iPad.